# Cannot align text next to image

Tags: html, css

Here is the result I need to achieve:

[image]

Here is what I have thus far:

[image]

As you can see, there are several updates to be made.

My questions are:

1./ How do I get the text next to the avatar to line up 10px to the right of the avatar. **Currently its being thrown below the avatar**.

2./ Once I align up the text next to the avatar, how do I then line up my text that sits at the very right? **I believe I can create a div and float right**

**I'm only a few days into CSS so I'm still a newbie so please any details would be phenomenial**

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="page">
    <table class="reviewsouter" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
     <td class="reviewleft">
      <div id="reviews">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="reviewuserinfo">
            <td>
                <div>test</div>
                <img class="avatar" src="/avatar/35274"/>           
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="reviewuserdata">
            <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
      </div>
      </td>
      <td class="reviewright"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

And Here is my CSS:

```
    @CHARSET "UTF-8";
    .page {
     position: relative;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
     border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;   
    }
    table {
     border:0px;
     width:100% 
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewleft{
     width:800px
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewright{
     width:400px
    }
    #reviewspotlight {
     position: relative;
     background-color:#000000;
     height:111px;
     z-index:19997;
     font-family: DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    #reviews {
      position: relative;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      color:#000000;
      border-right:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo {
      background-color:#f0f0f0;
      height:60px;
      border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;      
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo img.avatar{
      position:relative;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo div {
      display:block
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserdata {
      background-color:#ffffff;
      height: 315px;
      border-left:1px solid #ffffff;    
    }
```

Any help would be great.

**UPDATE**

Ok so I got this far now:

[image]

Here is my new HTML for this div(the `reviewuserinfo` div):

```
            <tr class="reviewuserinfo">
            <td width="60px"><img class="avatar" src="/act/avatar/35274"/></td>
            <td>Text2</td>
            <td align="right" style="padding-right:15px">Text3</td>
            </tr>
```

**What I need now is to move the text up so it starts at the same position as the top of the avatar - basically horizontal to the top of the image avatar**

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/107/

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
  <div class="left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
      <div class="left-content">
          <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
          <p>Posted bla bla</p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
      <p>Joined lorem ipsum</p>
      <p>12 reviews bla lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 body, h4, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.page {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    clear: both;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.left-content, img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: how do you make the text ling up horizontally with the image

Comment: `vertical-align: middle;` like dis.

Answer (score 0):

What if you simply add horizontal cells and include the image and text in each one of them?

Comment: `   <div class="page">
    <table class="reviewsouter" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="48" rowspan="2" class="reviewleft"><img class="avatar" src="/avatar/35274"/></td>
      <td class="reviewleft">Traveler</td>
      <td class="reviewright">Joined 2 years ago </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="782" class="reviewleft">
      <div id="reviews">posted on 15 May, 2008 </div>      </td>
      <td width="277" class="reviewright">12 reviews and 49 comments posted </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
`

Comment: How can I get the text to align horizontally with the image